# Java rest webservice client

Tags: java, rest, service, client

Please help me in creating a rest client for below rest service.

Endpoint url: http://xxxyyy.com

Header: Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

Header: Authorization : Basic: Base64encoded username and password

Body: grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=yyy

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You want us to write the entire code for you??

Comment: Try yourself first and come with impediments

Comment: I have posted my approach

Answer (score -1):

I tried below, dont know where to add the second header and body.

```
    String url = "http://xxx";
    String name = "xxx";
    String password = "yyy";
    String authString = name + ":" + password;
    String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
    ClientResponse resp = webResource.accep`enter code here`t("application/json")
                                     .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                                     .get(ClientResponse.class);





    if(resp.getStatus() != 200){
        System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
    }
    String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("response: "+output);
```

Comment: What are `Client`, `WebSource`, `ClientResponse`?